# Task list view permissions by department

Tags: sharepoint-online, task-list

I have a task list where task list of the entire company exists. I want task list can have permission to view such that a department member can only view his/her department tasks, but cannot view other department's tasks, and all tasks view is disabled.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily. Follow these steps:

**1. Create SharePoint Groups as per your departments.**

- Go to *Site Settings* > *People and groups* > *New Group* (with the name of your department e.x. HR, Marketing)
- Add users to these groups as per departments.

**2. Set Permissions to your Tasks Lists**

- Go to *List Settings* > *Permissions for this list* > *Stop Inheriting Permission*
- Check all groups and click on *Remove User Permissions* in the ribbon.
- Now in the ribbon, click on *Grant Permissions*. Add Group Name [HR/Marketing] which you want to give permissions for this list.

Now Login with user who is in HR group, He could see only those lists which have set permissions for HR group.

**EDIT:** If you have single task list with Department column then when you add new item to Tasks List then add SharePoint Group permission to Assign To Field:

[image]

Comment: But the problem is I have a single list, not many lists. This list has a department column. I want to hide list items if the current user's department is not equal to list item's department.

Comment: Then add 'Group' to "Assign To" column...

Comment: I don't want to assign a task to group. Assign it to a user then get the group of user from another list?

Comment: filter on Assign To..

Answer (score 0):

I assume a user can only have 1 department? or he/she is only a member of 1 department?

you could just filter the view by current user [me], and add the department to the view,

in that case, he can only see his task, he only have 1 department anyways. The list should be something like

[image]

This is a concept that I assume would work, let me know if it helps atleast.

Happy SharePointing!